# Why the Animator Controller is vanish from the Inspector and not assigned when running the game?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

It is assigned in the editor but when running the game in run time the Animator controller is gone and not assigned anymore.

I'm trying to play all the state animations in Animator controller one by one.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using System.Linq;
using UnityEditor.Animations;

public class SwitchAnimations : MonoBehaviour
{
    public AnimatorController controller;

    private Animator animator;
    private AnimatorState[] states;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start()
    {
        animator = GetComponent<Animator>();
        states = GetStateNames(animator);
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.A))
        {
            StartCoroutine(QueueAnim(states));
        }
    }

    private AnimatorState[] GetStateNames(Animator animator)
    {
        controller = animator ? animator.runtimeAnimatorController as AnimatorController : null;
        return controller == null ? null : controller.layers.SelectMany(l => l.stateMachine.states).Select(s => s.state).ToArray();
    }

    IEnumerator QueueAnim(params AnimatorState[] anim)
    {
        int index = 0;

        while (index < anim.Length)
        {
            if (index == anim.Length)
                index = 0;

            animator.Play(anim[index].name);

            AnimatorStateInfo si = animator.GetCurrentAnimatorStateInfo(index);
            yield return new WaitForSeconds(5);
            index++;
        }
    }
}
```

First all the variable in the script was private and this one was static :

```
private static AnimatorController controller;
```

And the method GetStateNames was static too :

```
private static AnimatorState[] GetStateNames(Animator animator)
```

But I changed the controller variable to be public and not static so the GetStateNames is not static now since the script is attached to empty GameObject.

But when I assign Animator Controller to the controller it's vanish when running the game.

Screenshot before running the game :

[image: Before running the game]

[image: After running the game]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears you are assigning an AnimatorController and not an Animator.  An Animator references/uses an AnimatorController but not the other way around.  Just make Animator public and assign it the AnimatorController.

Comment: I did and now there is another problem. The  animations never play when pressing on A it does nothing and throw many warnings for example : Invalid Layer Index '1'
UnityEngine.Animator:GetCurrentAnimatorStateInfo(Int32) man warnings on layer 1 some on layer 2 4 5 7 6 and more.  The warnings is on line 47 : AnimatorStateInfo si = animator.GetCurrentAnimatorStateInfo(index);

Comment: If I'm changing the line to layer 0 only : AnimatorStateInfo si = animator.GetCurrentAnimatorStateInfo(0); now there are no warnings but still it's doing anything not playing the states animations. .

Comment: Not 100%.  Break down `GetStateNames`.  Try just using `controller` as always the animator and go from there.